# Custom UIView like iCal event "bubbles"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icalendar

How would I go about creating a custom UIView that is like the event "bubbles" in iCal for iPhone?  I would prefer to not use images, so that they could be in any color.

Thanks!

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/609/screenshot20100205at120.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/609/screenshot20100205at120.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve many effects just playing with CALayer class. Matt Long had a nice [blog post](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/) about how to use it to make nice UIButtons - may be you'll be able to apply this approach to your needs as well.

Comment: Warning: cornerRadius and borderWidth can be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a rectangle with an arc at each corner. That gives you the shape. The highlight at the top to give it a shine can be done with a gradient drawn on top of the underlying layer. That should let you handle the color of the bubbles without resorting to images.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181279/smoothing-a-rounded-stroke-in-core-graphics/2181479#2181479) has some code to get you pointed in the right direction to draw rectangular shapes with arcs at the corner.