# Core Graphics rounded corner not sharp

Tags: ios, xamarin, core-graphics, rounded-corners, antialiasing

I am drawing rounded rectangle. Problem - corners are not sharp. Is there any solution for this problem?

[image: Zoom 100%]

[image: Zoomed in]

Here is my drawing code (Xamarin)

```
var thickness = (nfloat)Math.Min (Math.Min (_renderer.View.Thickness.Left, _renderer.View.Thickness.Right), Math.Max (_renderer.View.Thickness.Top, _renderer.View.Thickness.Bottom));
var path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect (new CGRect(this.Bounds.X + thickness / 2, this.Bounds.Y + thickness / 2, this.Bounds.Width - thickness, this.Bounds.Height - thickness), (nfloat)_renderer.View.CornerRadius);

context.SetShouldAntialias (true);
context.SetStrokeColor (_renderer.View.Color.ToCGColor ());
context.SetFillColor (_renderer.View.BackgroundColor.ToCGColor ());
path.LineWidth = thickness;

path.Fill ();
path.Stroke ();
```

Comment: Have you tried running that on an actual device vs the iOS simulator? You should also look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2181479/4984832

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a cornerradius instead ?

Btw you must check the scale property of your layer. It must be set the the same value as the mainview scale (i.e.: 2 on retina devices). And by default it is 1.